# How to "talk" to a "parent" IP in a subnet?

Tags: linux, networking, netcat, netbsd

I have access to just *nix systems. Either NetBSD and/or bare Linux-based OS.

So my question comes from the fact that `ADB` is not widely available on all platforms, if so is very hard to install or obtain (having access to internet, get super user access, etc).

Anyways, `RNDIS` functionality is already offered by almost all Android devices. Allowing the phone to become a "router" will give me the option to use netcat because I can just set up a "server" and get/receive files bidirectionally, without the need of getting `ADB` involved.

Like this:

```
NetBSD
dhcpcd -n urndis0

Linux
udhcpd -i usb0
```

That will give me an IP within a subnet set up by Android. Something like: `192.168.32.225/24`

So, essentially the phone acts as a router, giving my *nix computer an IP belonging to a subnet set up by the phone itself. I would like to just open a port on my localhost `127.0.0.1` with `netcat` and just transfer files.

Something like this:

```
On Android device:
busybox nc -v -w3 -l -p 3838

On *nix system (Linux in the example below):
nc -v -w3 **(upper higher loopdevice outside subnetted network) 127.0.0.24** 3838
```

And be able to access the "higher" network/loopdevice already existing within Android's own local network.

Let's assume the Android phone is another host sharing it's connection and assigning a subnet IP to my computer for that matter so my *nix box can access the internet:

**My question is then: Can I use the the IP (which is within a subnet) provided by the RNDIS interface of the Android phone to access the local network of the phone itself with just standard tools in *nix?**

**Solution**
@Frédéric Loyer Thank you very much!

Wonderful, with this method there is no need for me to get `adb` on each computer I'm on, most of the time what I got is `busybox nc` and or `ssh`. This is perfect, with this I can even ssh into my Android without even needing an active connection on the phone itself, isn't amazing!?

Here is what I did.

```
# This makes my computer to request an IP to my phone.
$sudo udhcpc -i usb0

# Since I got access to busybox-only most of the time, this gives me the IP from the "router" which is the phone.

$route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.42.129  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 usb0
127.0.0.1       *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 lo
192.168.42.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 usb0

# ifconfig output shows me the new IP assigned to usb0 on my computer.
```

After this is just a matter of ssh'ing onto my phone or open ports with Termux. Amazing! :)

Comment: what is a `higher IP`?

Comment: localhost does not route outside of the device ... it cannot be used to transfer files between devices

Comment: @jsotola When  subnetting happens a portion of one IP gets sliced into more IP lets say: `192.168.1.25` any subnet "under" that IP will belong just to that range `192.168.1.25/34` so I say the "parent" or "higher" IP is `192.168.1.25` either I don't fully understand how subnetting works and I'm terrible wrong or the word I chosen is not the right one.

Comment: @jsotola In regards routing. I know, local host will not be routing outside the device is running on. That's why I'm curious if such process can be done, if it's possible to escape that "slicing process". Lets say if my device is under `192.168.1.25/34` do I have the option, somehow with standard \*unix tools, to contact `192.168.1.25` from `192.168.32.225/34`?

About transferring files, as along as connection is established with two IPs, netcat can do it: `tar -vcf - ./my-files | nc -v -w3 -l -p 8585` and on the receiver is just ` nc 192.168.1.99 | tar -vxf -` I've done hundreds of times.

Comment: I didn’t understood « I would like to just open a port on my localhost 127.0.0.1 with netcat and just transfer files. ». The 127.0.0.1 is made to connect a device to itself. You won’t get a transfer from one system to an other with it. You use in your example, the address 127.0.0.4. Where does this address come from.

Comment: You said « That will give me an IP within a subnet set up by Android. Something like: 192.168.32.225/24 », then « When subnetting happens a portion of one IP gets sliced into more IP lets say: 192.168.1.25 any subnet "under" that IP will belong just to that range 192.168.1.25/34 » it seems contradictory. Could you explain more ?

Comment: My guess is that Linux (or NetBSD) will receive 2 addresses : one for itself and a router address which should be used as the default gateway. Try `nc` with this second address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Android phone, you have typed :

```
busybox nc -v -w3 -l -p 3838
```

This seems Ok.

On Linux, type `ip route`.  You should have something like this :

```
default via 37.59.40.254 dev enp1s0 onlink 
37.59.40.0/24 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 37.59.40.118
```

The line with the `default` route indicates the router address. (Here `37.59.40.254`). You should try to type `nc` from Linux with this router address since it is the Android address on the RNDIS subnet. You should type only one IP address : no 127.0.0.24. (127 adresses are reserved for internal exchanges within your Linux system).

There are no such things as slicing here : the Android creates a network which maybe `192.168.32.0/24`. On this network there are two addresses defined (one for both end), other addresses may not work.